# Best way to configure jenkins job running on different slaves

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to run a Jenkins job on 4 different slaves (windows, linux, solaris, Mac). Instead of making 4 different jobs I want to have a single job. I can use a Node parameter to execute on different slaves. My job runs a script which uses Jenkins workspace of slave and a few other scripts. My script is in a different folder on each slave, and other required scripts are in a different folder. So now I have created 4 different jobs for each slave and hard-coded Jenkins workspace and other required scripts path.

Is there any way so that I can put all paths in some JSON-like structure and depending on slave will pick those paths? So that I will have 1 job only.

Please suggest, Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the motivation for having a single job? Having four separate jobs titled `my-job-windows`, `my-job-solaris` etc seems like a good idea, especially if the job only fails on one platform where it will be much clearer to see what's happened.

Comment: I have 4 different project and each project has 6 different jobs. If I create separate jobs then I will have to create 96 jobs :)

Comment: You could look Matrix jobs https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin or possibly even code your jobs programatically with the job dsl https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my idea is to use e.g "**Execute system Groovy script**" to get slave value and then use if statement to assigne proper path and create parameter visible in  Environment Variables:

```
import hudson.model.Computer
import hudson.model.StringParameterValue
import hudson.model.ParametersAction

//get slave name
def slaveName = Computer.currentComputer().getNode().name
def path

//choose path
if(slaveName.equals("slave01")){
  path = "C:"
}
if(slaveName.equals("slave02")){
  path = "/root"
}
if(slaveName.equals("slave03")){
  path = "D:"
}

//pass path as env. variable
build.addAction(new ParametersAction(new StringParameterValue('path', path)))
```

then you can use variable path in command:
`echo %path%` 
or use **Conditional BuildStep Plugin** to set separable steps for each operation system and control when each step should be executed

Comment: I think I will give a try for this, looks helpful to me. Depending on slave it will pick all the paths, also it's easier to update/add/remove required path. I can add any number of paths, right?

Comment: Any idea why this is not working for me? def slaveName = Computer.currentComputer().getNode(), giving NullPointerException.

Comment: Where you put this code? I suspect in jenkins script console? (jenkins/script site). This script should be executed as part of the job in "Execute system Groovy script"

Comment: I am using scriptler plugin, I have created one script using above code and executing it in job using same plugin, still  not able to get node of running job.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is designed to check out files from a version control system (Subversion, Git, whatever) and run tasks. Instead of trying to manage separate files on separate slaves, you should put your scripts in some form of version control and let Jenkins check out the files in the workspace as part of its build process.

Comment: Yes, I am planning to do the same but even if I put it in some version control, doesn't solve my problem. I want to avoid hardcoded script.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your problem, perhaps you can clarify the question. If the script files are in version control, where does the "hardcoded script" come from?

Comment: I have some paths in script file those are hard-coded. e.g my script is demo.py, this script runs few other script those are in different folder on each slave. Hence for now I am hard-coding it in script file.

Comment: Why not put all the scripts into version control?

Comment: In future if I need to make any change in my script, I will have to do it for all the slaves. It will be hard to maintain those scripts.